# CSS margin top is working for every button not just for one

Tags: html, css, margin

I was watching a yt tutorial and I can't seem to find the answer to this question.
I just want to margin top a button at 600px and the other at 500 px

```css
.subscribe-button {
  background-color: rgb(200, 0, 0);
  color: white;
  border: none;
  height: 30px;
  width: 90px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 1px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 600px;
}

.join-button {
  background-color: white;
  border-color: rgb(13, 185, 253);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  color: rgb(13, 185, 253);
  height: 30px;
  width: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 500px;
}

.tweet-button {
  background-color: rgb(0, 195, 255);
  color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: none;
  height: 30px;
  width: 70px;
  cursor: progress;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<button class="subscribe-button">
  Subscribe
</button>
<button class="join-button">
  Join
</button>
<button class="tweet-button">
Tweet
</button>
```

This is the code
[this is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4bWD.png)

I tried what I said above and I expected it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the vertical alignment to something other than the default of basline, e.g.e. top:

```css
.subscribe-button {
  background-color: rgb(200, 0, 0);
  color: white;
  border: none;
  height: 30px;
  width: 90px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 1px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 600px;
}

.join-button {
  background-color: white;
  border-color: rgb(13, 185, 253);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  color: rgb(13, 185, 253);
  height: 30px;
  width: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 500px;
}

.tweet-button {
  background-color: rgb(0, 195, 255);
  color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: none;
  height: 30px;
  width: 70px;
  cursor: progress;
  font-weight: bold;
}

button {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<button class="subscribe-button">
  Subscribe
</button>
<button class="join-button">
  Join
</button>
<button class="tweet-button">
Tweet
</button>
```